# How to attach parameters to functional calls in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I uses Rails erb to create links, like the following:

`<% link_to item_path(topic.company, topic, :area => params[:area]) do %>`

However now I need to add some condition, when it fulfills I want to pass additional parameters to the item_path function. like:

`<% link_to item_path(topic.company, topic, :area => params[:area], :utm_source => "top") do %>`

I guess Ruby probably has a way to add additional parameters since parameter passing is essentially a hash right? Is there an cool way to do this, instead of an if-else statement calling item_path with different set of parameters (like in Java?).

P.S. I tried have one extra hash with the additional parameter and append it into the functional call, like the following. But it didn't work.

`<% link_to item_path(topic.company, topic, :area => params[:area], additional_param) do %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your arguments hash before calling `link_to`:

```
<% args = { :area => params[:area] } %>
<% args[:utm_source] = 'top' if(whatever) %>
<%= link_to item_path(topic.company, topic, args) do %>
    <!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

When you call a method like this:

```
o.m :where => 'is', :pancakes => 'house?'
```

Ruby automatically wraps the arguments in a hash so the above is the same as:

```
o.m { :where => 'is', :pancakes => 'house?' }
```

or even

```
h = { :where => 'is', :pancakes => 'house?' }
o.m h
```

Comment: also it seems like the params hash building code probably belongs in the controller or a helper method, not in the view

Comment: @Matthew: Probably but hard to say without more context.

Comment: thanks. I used Hash.merge! on top of this. About MVC, it is in a partial so a bit difficult to do that

Comment: @lulalala: My *Probably* above probably should have been *Possibly*. And `merge!` or assignments are fine, whatever works and is clearest to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
link_to item_path(topic.company, topic, :area => params[:area],
  :utm_source => ("top" if top?), :abc => (1 if bottom?))
```

The values for the hash keys will be set `nil` when the `if` condition is NOT met. The path helpers ignore the hash keys with `nil` values.

Comment: Thanks, I would definitely use this when only one additional parameter is needed.

Comment: This trick works well with `path` helpers only. The path helpers ignore the `nil` values.  eg: `experts_path(:age=>2, :foo=>nil)` results in `experts?age=2` instead of `experts?age=2&foo=nil`